# Generate Uuid manually in constructor or via UuidGenerator annotation

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, uuid

I am switching to [Ramsey\Uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid-doctrine) and don't know what is the intended way to generate the Uuids.

**Either** as shown in the examples with an anntoation:

```
/**
 * @var UuidInterface
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
 */
private $id;


public function __construct() {
}
```

**Or** manually in the constructor:

```
/**
 * @var UuidInterface
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
 */
private $id;


public function __construct() {
    $this->id = Uuid::uuid4();
}
```

In the second case, I do not understand how an existing id would be set during hydration. I added a public setter for testing purposes, but it is not called! In my understanding, when loading from db, a new object is created, which executes the constructor and hence sets a new uuid. Then somehow, this uuid must be replaced by the one from the db record. Am I missing something?

However the big advantage that the id is *available immediately* is gone when using the annotation, since the generation only takes place when calling `$em->persist(...)`.

There are also variants out there where the constructor takes an optional uuid argument and uses it if not null.

Comment: Either approach of specifying how the uuid is generated will work and I won't comment upon which is best.  But as far as hydration is concerned, Doctrine uses reflection to directly set the values of your properties.  (Also uses reflection to get the values when persisting).  So the constructor is never called nor will any of your getter/setters be called.  Just direct mapping to and from a database table.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you can give a comment on how the reflection approach works?

Comment: [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) works great when used appropriately.