# Doctrine Symfony ORM not generating MySQL UUID with PHP 7.2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine

I cannot get ORM annotations to work so that the UUID is auto-generated in MySQL after the new entity added to the table is flushed. Here is my code:

Entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    protected $id;
```

In my controller:

```
    /**
     * @RestRoute\Post("")
     * @RestRoute\Post("/")
     */
    public function createAction($version, Request $request)
    {
        $res = $this->getManager()->createFromData(
            (array) $request->request->all()
        );

        if ($res) {
            return new JsonResponse($request->request->all());
        }
    }
```

And in my service/manager

```
    /**
     * Adds a new record to the entity table
     *
     * @param   CwPackageType   $data
     * @return  CwPackageType   the newly created entity
     * @throws  Exception       throws database/doctrine exception
     */
    public function createFromData($data)
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

        try {
            $rec = (new CwPackageType())->createFromData($data);

            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($rec);
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush($rec);
            $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->commit($rec);

            return $rec;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->rollback();

            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

When the record is added to the table, the ID field is left as null/blank. If I set the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode on MySQL I get an error when trying to add the record to the database:

```
General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

Without that mode, the record is added, but the UUID is null/blank

Note also that if I use the following annotation, the auto generated ID is properly created and stored in the ID field in the table

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have not done this myself but I'm pretty sure you need to install a uuid generator and tell doctrine to use it.  Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045546/generate-uuid-manually-in-constructor-or-via-uuidgenerator-annotation).  I'm sure there is an official example in the docs somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help, as I do not need to generate the UUID before the  insertion of the new entity into the database

Comment: Of course you do.  The mysql database is not going to do it for you.  It is not like auto increment.  Unless you want to mess around with triggers and stuff like that.

Comment: Cerad, correct, it is not MySql that generates the UUID, but Doctrine that does it behind the scenes based on the annotations. I have fixed the problem, it was an issue of namespacing and using subfolders in my directory structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this does not answer your question, but I think it might still be helpful. One of the advantages of UUID is, that they can be generated before inserting the entity. That means you have an identifier before it's saved that you can refer to. In order for this to work, you would use a library to generate a UUID and then perform this in the constructor. The most common one for this, as far as I can tell, is [ramsey/uuid](https://packagist.org/packages/ramsey/uuid) and in the context of Symfony and Doctrine [ramsey/uuid-doctrine](https://packagist.org/packages/ramsey/uuid-doctrine). With this your entity would probably look something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid")
     */
    private $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = Uuid::uuid4();
    }

    public function getId(): string
    {
        return $this->id->toString();
    }

    //...
}
```

If you don't like this, you will still be able to reuse your old logic, just switch to a custom generator, pointing to the one from the library:

```
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
```